# error " x2 = ptFC2XCoordDict[i+1] KeyError: 1" python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I don't understand why it doesn't work, i used this script three days ago and it totally works, i start today but i just changed my files and one field "Id_u" .
I changed this line:

```
arcpy.JoinField_management (outTable, "NEAR_FID", ptFC2, "OBJECTID", "Id_u")
```

instead of :

```
arcpy.JoinField_management (outTable, "NEAR_FID", ptFC2, "OBJECTID",["Id_basias","Id_basol","Id_irep","Id_mines","Id_icpe"])
```

here my script:

```
import arcpy,math,csv,time
print "Imports OK"
#debut du calcul de duree du script
tmps1=time.time()

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def calcul():
# Mise en place des variables de chemins d'acces des input et de la table de sortie
# Indiquer le chemin d'acces dans une geodatabase de la 1ere couche en entree (Cas) 
    ptFC1 = "C:/Users/m.mespoulhe/Desktop/ESTEBAN.gdb/"+ fichier_etud
# Indiquer le chemin d'acces dans une geodatabase de la 2ere couche en entree (industries)
    ptFC2 = "C:/Users/m.mespoulhe/Desktop/ESTEBAN.gdb/industries_et_sites_plomb_test1"
# indiquer le chemin d'acces a la geodatabase de sortie, ou sera generee la table de distances
    outGDB = "C:/Users/m.mespoulhe/Desktop/ESTEBAN.gdb"
# Le nom de la table generee, nommee par rapport a la 1ere couche en entree [-14:] est defini par rapport au nombre de caracteres du fichier de point en entree ptFC1 
    outTableName = fichier_etud +"_matrice_distances"
    outTable = outGDB + "/" + outTableName
    table = outTable
#Chemin + nom du fichier .txt en sortie 
    outfile = "C:/Users/m.mespoulhe/Desktop/resultats/"+ outTableName +"_txt"

    # Creation de la table de sortie ainsi que des champs (vides)
    arcpy.CreateTable_management(outGDB,outTableName)
    arcpy.AddField_management(outTable,"INPUT_FID","LONG")
    arcpy.AddField_management(outTable,"NEAR_FID","LONG")
    arcpy.AddField_management(outTable,"DISTANCE","DOUBLE")
    print "Creation de table de sortie OK"

# Creation et peuplement d'un dictionnaire portant les coodonnees X et d'un autre portant
# les coordonnees Y de la couche ptFC2 pour chaques OBJECTID en utilisant un SearchCursor
    ptFC2XCoordDict = {}
    ptFC2YCoordDict = {}
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ptFC2,["OBJECTID","SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            ptFC2XCoordDict[row[0]] = row[1][0]
            ptFC2YCoordDict[row[0]] = row[1][1]

# Open an InsertCursor ready to have rows written for each pair of OBJECTIDs
    iCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outTable,["INPUT_FID","NEAR_FID","DISTANCE"])
# Use a SearchCursor to read the rows (and X,Y coordinates) of the first
# feature class
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ptFC1,["OBJECTID","SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor: 
            x1 = row[1][0]
            y1 = row[1][1]
            for i in range(len(ptFC2XCoordDict)):
                x2 = ptFC2XCoordDict[i+1]
                y2 = ptFC2YCoordDict[i+1]
            # Prepare and insert the InsertCursor row
                iRow = [row[0],i+1,math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))]
                print iRow
                if math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1)) < 5000 :
                    iCursor.insertRow(iRow)
    del iCursor
    print "Calcul des distances OK"

#jointure des champs d'identifiants d'industries et des cas 
    arcpy.JoinField_management (outTable, "INPUT_FID", ptFC1, "OBJECTID", ["ID_OGS","ID_Esteban"]) 
    arcpy.JoinField_management (outTable, "NEAR_FID", ptFC2, "OBJECTID", "Id_u")
    print "Jointure des champs identifiants OK"


# Creation d'une liste de tous les champs de la table
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(table)
    field_names = [field.name for field in fields]

    with open(outfile,'wb') as f:
        dw = csv.DictWriter(f,field_names)
    # Ecriture des noms de champs dans le fichier de sortie
        dw.writeheader()

    # Ecriture du fichier avec le curseur 
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,field_names) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                dw.writerow(dict(zip(field_names,row)))
    print "Export de la table " + fichier_etud + " en .txt OK"

fichier_etud = "geocodage_esteban_PACA"

calcul()

tmps2=time.time()-tmps1
print "Temps d'execution = %f" %tmps2

print "Fait!"
```

and the error message:

> Imports OK Creation de table de sortie OK
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\m.mespoulhe\Desktop\script_distances_COMPLET.py", line 85,
>   in 
>       calcul()   File "C:\Users\m.mespoulhe\Desktop\script_distances_COMPLET.py", line 52,
>   in calcul
>       x2 = ptFC2XCoordDict[i+1] KeyError: 1

Comment: Try placing field name in a list: `arcpy.JoinField_management (outTable, "NEAR_FID", ptFC2, "OBJECTID", ["Id_u"])`. You should not combine paths with +, instead use use.path.join. Are you sure the objectid field is named OBJECTID? It will depend on your input. Use `OID@` token in cursors instead. That way it will Always work.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer, i folllow your advices. and in my both shapes (ptFC1 and ptFC2), i forgot to retire the "ObjectifID" column, so i couldn't have my join  with 2 colums called OBJECTID and OBJECTID_1. The real OBJECTID called OBJECTID_1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've assumed that your OBJECTID field is continuously populated from 1 to N. It's pretty likely that isn't the case.

Instead of using `range` you could use `keys`; something like this:

```
#Use a SearchCursor to read the rows (and X,Y coordinates) of the first
# feature class
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ptFC1,["OBJECTID","SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor: 
            x1 = row[1][0]
            y1 = row[1][1]
            for i in ptFC2XCoordDict.keys(): # using .keys() here
                x2 = ptFC2XCoordDict[i] # not incrementing the keys here
                y2 = ptFC2YCoordDict[i] # or here
            # Prepare and insert the InsertCursor row
                iRow = [row[0],i,math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))] # Also not incremented here anymore
                print iRow
                if math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1)) < 5000 :
                    iCursor.insertRow(iRow)
```

The one thing to keep in mind is that `keys` returns the keys in an arbitrary order. I can't tell if that matters or not, but if they need to be in order you could use `sorted`:

```
for i in sorted(ptFC2XCoordDict.keys()):
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that with Python 2.x, `keys` will return the entire list of keys at once. If your dictionaries are large and/or if you have concerns about memory usage, you can use `iterkeys` instead, which is an iterator as the name suggests.

Comment: I found my mistake , it was in the "industries_et_sites_plomb_test1" and "geocodage_esteban_PACA", i forgot to retire the OBJECTID .